# What is the "analytic" analogue of the valuative criterion of properness

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff complex analytic space. Below, let $D$ be the open unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $D^*$ be the punctured open unit disc.

I am looking for an analogue of the valuative criterion of properness in complex analysis.

Is the following correct?

> > The complex analytic space $X$ is compact if every holomorphic map $D^*\to X$ extends to a holomorphic map $D\to X$.

The converse implication is not true, because there are non-extendable maps from $D^*$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$, e.g., $z\mapsto \exp(-1/z^2)$.

I am thinking of $D^*$ as Spec $K$ and $D $ as Spec $R$, where $R$ is a dvr with fraction field $K$.

Comment: Elliptic curves also don't satisfy this property: write an elliptic curve E as $\mathbb{C}^{\times }/q^{\mathbb{Z}} $. The projection map $D^* \to E $ does not extend because the loop around $0$ in $D$ maps to a non trivial element in the homology of $E $. Jacobian of curves also fail to satisfy the property. What happens for Riemann surfaces of genus at least $2$?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Compact Riemann surfaces of genus at least two are Kobayashi hyperbolic. If $X$ is a Kobayashi hyperbolic compact space $X$, Kwack proved that every holomorphic map $\Delta^\ast\to X$ extends to a holomorphic map $\Delta \to X$. The original reference is "Generalization of the big Picard theorem" in Annals of Math. Second Series, Vol. 90, No. 1 (Jul., 1969), pp. 9-22 (14 pages). LAter Kobayashi generalized Kwack's theorem to non-compact "hyperbolic" spaces; see Chapter 6 of his book "Hyperbolic Complex Spaces".

Comment: @Sjoerd The property you are interested in is also studied in Section 3.2 of  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.09338.pdf  , and in Do Duc Thai and Pascal J. Thomas. *D-extension property without hyperbolicity.* Indiana Univ. Math. J., 47(3): 1125-1130, 1998.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the open disk in $\mathbb C$ is a counterexample (removable singularity theorem plus maximum principle).

Comment: Ok. That's of course correct. But what if I assume $X$ is quasi-projective in addition?

Comment: It's true in the quasi projective case: if there's a point in the projective closure not in $X$, cut by hyperplanes through that point to reduce to the case of a curve, which is then a punctured Riemann surface qed.